# SQL - one text box writing to multiple fields

Tags: sql

I have a SQL table called `Profiles` which includes columns `Username,Team1 & Team2`

When a user enters a text value (i.e. Man Utd) in the text box on an aspx page and clicks the Submit button the value entered shoud be written to `Team1 WHERE Username = Session"Username"` and the text box value should be deleted (i.e. the text box is empty)

When the user enters another value in the same text box (i.e. Man City) and clicks Submit, the value entered should be written to `Team2 WHERE Username = Session"Username"`.

I can achieve the first part of this operation where I write to `Team1` but I can't do the `Team2` bit.

Any help on the SQL query side of this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you edit the post with what you have tried?

Comment: Show your code please.

Comment: This is really an ASPX question, not a SQL question.

Comment: What happens when a user enters and submits a value third,forth... time?

Answer (score 0):

For your question I can suggest this solution:

1) You need to now that there is any record for your current user:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Profiles WHERE Username = {0} -- Set {0} = Session"Username"
```

If result is null or 0 it means that there is no record else yes:

. . . 1. No) Add a new record to your table without teams:
. . . . .`INSERT INTO Profiles VALUES ({0}, null, null) -- Set {0} = Session"Username"`

2) Now you have a record of your current user in `Profiles`. so :

After 1st. submit:

```
UPDATE Profiles SET Team1 = {1} WHERE Username = {0}
-- Set {0} = Session"Username"` & Set {1} = Team1.Text
```

And after 2nd. submit:

```
UPDATE Profiles SET Team2 = {1} WHERE Username = {0}
-- Set {0} = Session"Username"` & Set {1} = Team2.Text
```